# Dropping Elasticsearch requests when the system is overloaded

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a good way of dropping Elasticsearch requests when a system is overloaded? I know ES has a system of bulk rejections when it is overwhelmed but I would like a way to prevent any overloading by dropping requests to ES and my system when a certain threshold/limit is reached. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html#modules-threadpool), you can put a limit on the requests by bounding the `queue_size`. The default value of queue is -1 which means it does not have any upper bound for handling queries.

Each request (operation) has its own thread pool and each thread pool can be one of 2 types of a) fixed and b) fixed_auto_queue_size.

Bounding the fixed one:

```
thread_pool:
    [request/operation]:
        queue_size: X
```

fixed auto one:

```
thread_pool:
    [request/operation]:
        queue_size: X
        min_queue_size: Y
        max_queue_size: Z
```

Answer (score 0):

So there is multiple factors which you need to control:

1) Check your bulk performance with `curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool` , You will get how much records is in queue and how much records got rejected. [Check this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-thread-pool.html) for more info According to your traffic set bulk queue size and index queue size as [mentioned here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html).

`thread_pool.bulk.size: 24
thread_pool.bulk.queue_size: 200`

`thread_pool.index.size : 24
thread_pool.index.queue_size : 200`

Here 24 is number of core cpus, Which make sure your all CPU should used.

2) Once above settings done, Elasticsearch will just accept your request in bulk and it will queued your all data as per specified size. But once your traffic crossed your bulk queue size it will again start rejection. So make sure you are making constant bulk request in specific interval.

3) Increase your refresh interval. By default it set to 1s which means your doc will available for search after one second, But its expensive operation so make it 30s or else which fit to your ES cluster. So your doc will be available for search after 30 sec.

4) For more info you can refer this https://gist.github.com/ashishtiwari1993/004a19f4a44efc214403a7fc1ee27cda